# CockroachDB: Simple SQL queries do not respond

Tags: sql, cockroachdb

I have setup CockroachDB according to the instructions at https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/deploy-cockroachdb-on-premises-insecure.html. However, SQL queries take too long time and do not respond.

The procedure of setupping cluster is as follows. I used three machines running Ubuntu 19.10.

```
At node1
cockroach start --insecure --advertise-addr=${NODE1} --join=${NODE1},${NODE2},${NODE3} --cache=.25 --max-sql-memory=.25 --background

At node2
cockroach start --insecure --advertise-addr=${NODE2} --join=${NODE1},${NODE2},${NODE3} --cache=.25 --max-sql-memory=.25 --background

At node3
cockroach start --insecure --advertise-addr=${NODE3} --join=${NODE1},${NODE2},${NODE3} --cache=.25 --max-sql-memory=.25 --background
```

Here, ${NODEi} stands for the address of each node.

Then, I initialized the cluster.

```
cockroach init --insecure --host=${NODE1}
```

After that, I went into SQL shell and typed a query.

```
#
# Welcome to the CockroachDB SQL shell.
# All statements must be terminated by a semicolon.
# To exit, type: \q.
#
# Server version: CockroachDB CCL v20.1.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, built 2020/05/19 14:46:06, go1.13.9) (same version as client)
# Cluster ID: 77cf3b29-f895-45ab-9592-7956a3effdb7
#
# Enter \? for a brief introduction.
#
root@192.168.10.131:26257/defaultdb> CREATE DATABASE bank;
```

The command `CREATE DATABASE bank` took more than one minute and seemed not to work. But when I try again later, the same command finished within a second.

The status of cluster is as follows:

```
  id |       address        |     sql_address      |  build  |            started_at            |            updated_at            | locality | is_available | is_live
-----+----------------------+----------------------+---------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+----------+--------------+----------
   1 | 192.168.10.131:26257 | 192.168.10.131:26257 | v20.1.1 | 2020-05-28 05:00:17.725807+00:00 | 2020-05-28 05:26:01.338089+00:00 |          | true         | true
   2 | 192.168.10.132:26257 | 192.168.10.132:26257 | v20.1.1 | 2020-05-28 05:00:18.574806+00:00 | 2020-05-28 05:26:02.121931+00:00 |          | true         | true
   3 | 192.168.10.133:26257 | 192.168.10.133:26257 | v20.1.1 | 2020-05-28 05:00:18.729008+00:00 | 2020-05-28 05:26:02.253278+00:00 |          | true         | true
(3 rows)
```

Do you have any ideas to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't look expected, perhaps it's related to the network topology of your cluster or the clusters resources at the time of the statement.

If this is still an issue there are two things we could try:

a) Upgrading to the latest stable version of 20.2 which introduces a ton of stability and performance upgrades.

b) Collect a [debug.zip](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/cockroach-debug-zip.html#generate-a-debug-zip-file) and you could submit a ticket to [www.support.cockroachlabs.com](http://www.support.cockroachlabs.com) for the technical support team to check out.

I recommend upgrading to the latest stable version of v20.1 or v20.2 and giving that a shot though!